# Como alterar o state do componente pai pelo componente filho?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

tenho um componente de um modal (filho) que quero exibir uma informação ao clicar no objeto do componente pai.

Filho:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class ModalExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.props.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            showModal(!this.props.modalVisible);
        }}>
        <Text>Estou Funcionando!</Text>
        <Button
            color = "#b0bec5"
              title="Sair"
              onPress={() => {
                showModal(!this.props.modalVisible);
              }}
            />
      </Modal>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Pai:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Button } from 'react-native';

import ModalDescriptions, { setModalVisible } from './commons/modalDescriptions';
import api from '../service/api';

export default class budgetList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            budgetlist: [],
            modalVisible: false,
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        await api.get()
        .then(res => {this.setState({ budgetlist: res.data })});
    }

    showModal(visible) {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible })
    }

    handleDescription = (i) => {
        const data = this.state.budgetlist;
        this.setState({ desc: data[i].description });
      };


    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                this.showModal(true);
                this.handleDescription(index);
                }}>
                <View style={styles.entrace}>
                    <Text style={styles.customer}>{item.customer}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.value}>{item.value}</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.seller}>Vendedor: {item.seller}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );

    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <FlatList 
            keyExtractor={budgetlist => budgetlist.id.toString()}
            data={this.state.budgetlist}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />

            <ModalDescriptions />
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Ao clicar no item do componente pai eu consigo exibir o modal, porém ao clicar no botão Sair, ele diz que função `modalVisible` é `undefined`.

Estou aprendendo React e eu entendo que isso está ocorrendo porque não está sendo possível alterar o state do componente pai, porém como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Cara, eu não entendo muito de React pois só trabalhei com Vue.js, mas nestes casos o componente filho emite um evento e o componente pai escuta este evento... quando o evento ocorrer o componente pai altera seu próprio estado.

Comment: Você quer que o componente filho dispare uma função no componente pai?

Comment: Isso, e que altere o state do componente pai... isso é correto ou não é uma boa pratica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, o "modalVisible" é uma propriedade do state do componente pai. Uma forma de alterar ele a partir do componente filho seria passar a função "showModal" do componente pai como props para o componente modal. Seria algo assim:

```
<MeuComponente exibir={this.state.modalVisible} executar={this.showModal.bind(this)} />
```

O "MeuComponente" vai receber uma função dentro da props "executar" e o valor atual do state "modalVisible" dentro da props exibir

Dentro do modal, para executar, você faria assim:

```js
<Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.props.exibir}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.props.executar(!this.props.exibir);
        }}>
        <Text>Estou Funcionando!</Text>
        <Button
            color = "#b0bec5"
              title="Sair"
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.executar(!this.props.exibir);
              }}
            />
      </Modal>
```

Comment: funcionou muito obrigado!